# Count value checked and input

Tags: jquery, prestashop-1.7

I'm looking for a way to get all the values ​​check and all the values ​​enter the input in one and the same table.

These are my checkboxes and my inputs. If the user adds fields by clicking on the + it will add them to the array.

[image: array]

My Template:

```
    {if $familyUser && $product.is_travel|intval === 1}
    <div id="family_block_product">
        <h3 class="green_title"><span>{l s='Ajouter des participants'}</span></h3>
        {foreach $familyUser as $user}
            {if $user->active == 1}
                <div class="input-group">
                    <div class="input-group-prepend">
                        <div class="input-group-text">
                            <p>
                                <input type="checkbox"
                                       value="#{$user->id_block_family} {$user->surname|escape:'htmlall':'UTF-8'} {$user->name|escape:'htmlall':'UTF-8'}"
                                       class="userChecked_{$user->id_block_family}" name="userChecked[]">
                                {$user->surname|escape:'htmlall':'UTF-8'} {$user->name|escape:'htmlall':'UTF-8'}
                            </p>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            {/if}
        {/foreach}
        <div class="field_wrapper">

            <a href="javascript:void(0);" class="add_button_blockproducttravel" title="Add field"><img
                        class="img-responsive"
                        src="/modules/blockproducttravel/img/add-icon.png"
                        width="20"/></a>

        </div>
        <p class="last_p">{l s='Votre enfant n\'est pas sur la liste : ' mod='blockproducttravel'}<a
                    href="{$link->getModuleLink('blockfamily', 'myfamily')|escape:'html'}">{l s='modifiez votre foyer' mod='blockproducttravel'}</a>
        </p>
    </div>
{/if}
```

Here is my HTML / Smarty template, knowing that after I will have to recover this table is the record in database.

Here is what I already did.

```
    $(document).ready(function(){
    var maxField = 10; //Input fields increment limitation
    var addButton = $('.add_button_blockproducttravel'); //Add button selector
    var wrapper = $('.field_wrapper'); //Input field wrapper
    var fieldHTML = '<div class="form-group">' +
        '<label class="col-md-4" for="nameGuest">Nom & Prénom</label>' +
        '<div class="col-md-8">' +
        '<input class="form-control nameGuest" type="text" name="field_name[]"/>' +
        '<a href="javascript:void(0);" class="remove_button_blockproducttravel">' +
        '<img class="img-responsive" src="/modules/blockproducttravel/img/Remove_Item_icon.png" width="20" />' +
        '</a></div>';
    var x = 0;
    var counted = 0;
    var participants = [];

    $(addButton).click(function(e){
        if(x < maxField){
            x++;
            counted++;
            $('#quantity_wanted').val(counted);
            $(wrapper).append(fieldHTML);
        }
    });

    //Once remove button is clicked
    $(wrapper).on('click', '.remove_button_blockproducttravel', function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        $(this).parent().parent('div').remove(); //Remove field html
        x--; //Decrement field counter
        counted--;
        $('#quantity_wanted').val(counted);
    });

    $("#family_block_product input[name='userChecked[]']").change(function (event) {
        if ($(this).is(':checked')) {
            counted++;
            $('#quantity_wanted').val(counted);
            participants.push(event.target.value);
            console.log(participants);
        } else {
            counted--;
            $('#quantity_wanted').val(counted);
            // TODO Faire la suppression de l'utilisateur lorsqu'on décoche
        }
    });
});
```

Thank you for your help.

Comment: Please create a working snippet of your code that reproduces the problem. We can't read the html from an image.

Comment: sorry I had forgotten him

Comment: You can create code snippets in stackoverflow where you put your html/js/css code. However it can not do server side logic. Therefore when you got client side issues it's best to recreate your problem with the least amount of code as an example so people can help you faster. https://stackoverflow.blog/2014/09/16/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/